# JavaScript Error: sendMessage is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to call a function from another module and I have included the function in the module.exports but whenever I try to call the function I am given an error `TypeError: messenger.sendMessage is not a function`.

Here are the code snippets:

```
// messenger.js sendMessage is the function that is not working

    function sendMessage(recipient, recipientmessage, callback){
    var options = {
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        method: "POST",
        qs: {access_token:process.env.FB_MESSENGER_TOKEN},
        json:{
            recipient: {
                id: recipient
            },
            message:{
                text: recipientmessage
            }
        }
    };

    request(options,function(error,incomingMessage,response){
        if (!error){
            if (callback){
                callback()
            }
        }
    });

}

module.exports = {
    router:router,
    sendMessage: sendMessage
};
```

Here is the module where I am calling the imported module:

```
        let Intent = require(__dirname + "/intent-model.js");
    let messenger = require(__dirname + "/../app/routes/messenger.js");

    function smalltalk(intent){

//this sendMessage does not work and I am getting the error: TypeError: messenger.sendMessage is not a function     

        messenger.sendMessage(intent.accountID, "Hey how are you", function(callback){
           console.log("I do not understand why this isnt working");

        });

    }

    module.exports = {
        smalltalk: smalltalk
    };
```

If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated. I can give more code or information if necessary.

Comment: Do you have this on github or somewhere?

Comment: What is the `typeof` `messenger`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate it is just a regular module I created you can see the module.exports at the bottom

Comment: @s_kirkiles I see that. I mean what does `typeof(messenger)` give from within `smalltalk`?

Comment: It outputs object. What I am thinking is going on is some sort of requirement issues. Could there be a problem if one module requires another module which in turn requires the module that required it creating a bad loop?

Comment: Yes this was the issue. There was a problem with circular dependency so I had to do some sort of lazy loading to get everything to work properly.